# how to insert an empty value in mysql date type field?

Tags: php, mysql, date

How to insert a NULL or empty value in a mysql date type field (NULL = yes).

If I try to insert an empty value it inserts 0000-00-00 but I want to keep it empty or NULL.

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

Please see that I have set default value as NULL

```
  `payment_due_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
```

Ok OKies

I have got it working now

```
function get_mysqlDate($date, $delimiter='/') {
    if(check_empty($date)) {
        return 'NULL';
    }
    list($d, $m, $y) = explode($delimiter, $date);
    //$datetime = strtotime($date);
    return "'".date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$m, $d, $y))."'";
}




"... SET mydate = ".get_mysqldate($_POST['mydate'])." ...."
```

Cheers

Comment: Are you actually inserting an empty String or really NULL? (or not specifing anything) Maybe the empty string is interpreted as 0000-00-00

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72169592/2847436 this resolved my problem...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If that's happening, it's because the column has been defined with `NOT NULL` or with a `default '0000-00-00'`.  You need to change the column definition to allow `NULL`s and have no default.

Your insert should be specifying NULL, as well, not `''`, if that's what you mean by "empty value".

Comment: I have mentioned that I have set NULL = yes and default value as NULL as well.

Comment: And you have NULL not 'NULL' in your statement? "INSERT ... VALUES (NULL, 1, 2)"

Answer (score 2):

phew.. was struggling with this null thing a bit.

I had a php script that copies, formats and stores data from one database A to database B. there was a date field in database A with NULL values. but when I copied it it became 0000-00-00 in my database B.

finally figure out it was because I was putting single quotes around NULL like ('NULL').

```
$started_date = mysql_result($databaseA['result'],$i,"start_date");

    if (empty($published_at_date)){
     $insert_sql .= "NULL,  ";
    } 
    else 
    {
     $insert_sql .= " '" . mysql_real_escape_string($started_date) ."', ";
    }
```

This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the field when your doing your insert.

Say your table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
`name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`payment_due_on` date DEFAULT NULL);
```

If you want to insert something without the date, use:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('name here');
```