# MySQL updating nullable date column to NULL

Tags: mysql, date, null

I have a nullable date column in a MySQL InnoDB table. How do I update that column to NULL when issuing an update?

```
UPDATE memo_codes_student SET `resolved_date_client` = NULL, `status` = 'Rejected' WHERE `guid_enrollment` = @guid_enrollment AND `guid` = @itemGUID
```

When I run the statement above, it updates the field to 0000-00-00. How can I get it to update the field to NULL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert an empty value in mysql date type field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137655/how-to-insert-an-empty-value-in-mysql-date-type-field)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to figure out how to UPDATE a date field to null rather than insert

Comment: date type doesn't have null value any way otherwise insert or update.

Comment: Please provide `show create table memo_codes_student` and `show variables like 'sql_mode';`.

Comment: Interesting: [mySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-date.html) The special “zero” date '0000-00-00' can be stored and retrieved as '0000-00-00'. When a '0000-00-00' date is used through Connector/ODBC, it is automatically converted to NULL because ODBC cannot handle that kind of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running in [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) mode.

See this post for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3891947/1602014

Comment: I don't think that 'mode' explains it.