# json_decode returns null instead of NULL on post request, prevents me to set NULL in the DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null

I am having the issue that I need to be able to put a NULL value in a mysql database. So from the frontend I send a basic javascript object:

```
{
 "Info": {
  "Name": "Michelangelo",
  "Date" : null
  }
}
```

In my PHP file I do get the request correctly and decode it:

```
if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)) {
  // Extract the data.
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
}
```

It works for strings, booleans, ints correctly but not for `null` values. It will output in PHP after decoding like `null` and not `NULL`. As far as I know the only correct value in PHP is NULL:https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

I put the values like this in DB. Date column is of type date and it accepts `NULL` values. However with `null` it will be converted to 0000-00-00;

```
  $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET 
  `Username`='$request->Info->Name',
  `Date`='$request->Info->Date' //DB accepts NULL but not null (tested)
  WHERE `id` = '{$id}' LIMIT 1";
```

So why does it not convert correctly? I know I can loop over the object and replace all the `null` with `NULL` values, but since the object has nesting it will be a major headache. How can I solve this and why does this happen? I would prefer to do this with PHP and not in the sql query.

Comment: You should be using prepared statements and bind variables, this (AFAIK) will solve your problem.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859629/mysql-updating-nullable-date-column-to-null

Comment: The problem is the quotes around your null value is making mysql interpret it as a string. `'$request->Info->Date'` Also, `null === NULL` in php btw.

Comment: Can you use without quotes around it like `{$request->Info->Date}`

Comment: `{
 "Info": {
  "Name": "Michelangelo",
  "Date" : null
}` is  invalid json thats the reason why json_decode returns null..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Fixed. Json is correct in my real code

Comment: in that case post more code so we can see flow control ..

Comment: Are we debugging PSEUDO code??? Thats wont work, you only get Pseudo answers and comments

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is a simplified version. What is the problem? You want to read more columns?

Comment: @SravanthPujari That will give me an error.

Comment: @Michelangelo See my answer

Comment: @fonini does not work. It will still insert the 0000-00-00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because you are putting the "null" between single quotes!

```
`Date`='$request->Info->Date'
```

Solution: Use bind parameters in your prepared statement.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
$sth = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET
  `Username`=:username, `Date`=:date
  WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1");
$sth->bindParam(':username', $request->Info->Name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':date', $request->Info->Date);
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id);
$sth->execute();
```

You should build some validation class where it will return the proper (sanitized) values from the Request that you are going to use in the query.

Consider creating some class/logic like

```
final class InfoRequest
{
    /** @var array */
    private $info;

    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->info = $request->Info;
    }

    public function date(): ?string
    {
        $date = $this->info['Date'];
        if (!$this->isValidDate($date)) {
            throw NotValidDateException();
        }
        if (!$date) {
            return null;
        }
        $dateTime = new \DateTime($this->info['Date']);

        return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    private function isValidDate($date): bool
    {
        return true; // TODO: Not implemented yet
    }

    public function name(): string
    {
        $name = $this->info['Name'];
        if (!$this->isValidName($name)) {
            throw NotValidNameException();
        }

        return $name;
    }

    private function isValidName($name): bool
    {
        return true; // TODO: Not implemented yet
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$info = new InfoRequest($request);
$sth->bindParam(':username', $info->name(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Apart from that, you should never pass the direct input from the request into a raw query to the DB.

Comment: Thnx will get on it. I haven't been doing PHP for a long time so I didn't know that sanatizing was so crucial for getting the correct values. I was going to do this at a later moment but I didn't think it would cause me problems when I didn't.

Comment: In the comments below the question they are more concernd about the simplified version of code that I posted, but why when I var_dump the request it tells me NULL but later on it is magically converted to null? Just a quirk of sql in combination with php?

Comment: I don't follow you, sorry. Could you give me more details about the context of your question?

Comment: When I `var_dump` the decoded json in another file (not coming from a request) it converts the json null's to correct NULL values in PHP. I find it strange that when do this from a request it converts json null to null in PHP.

Comment: Yes, for sure, @Dharman, I just rush in my example. You're absolutely right :)

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea not to take the values directly from user input (no matter how much you think you should trust the source).  See also [obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Since you're now mapping and cleansing the data as you build your query (probably using prepared statements), it should be trivial to map the value `null` to the string `"NULL"` (or just let the prepared statement library handle it).

Comment: Thnx, maybe will try to do it with prepared statements. I was going to do that at a later moment, but then I found myself with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to the variations of NULL or null.
In PHP they are the same thing.

You are probably running in MySQL NO_ZERO_DATE mode, which fills null dates with zeroes. The command below changes the way that null dates are handled by MySQL.

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891896/blocking-0000-00-00-from-mysql-date-fields/3891947#3891947).

Comment: Does this solve the problem of null being converted to 0000-00-00, or just block the ability to set a date to 0000-00-00?

Comment: From the MySQL manual: "MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE mode."

Comment: Tried it, this is not preventing `0000-00-00`values.